# При исполнении цикла не появляется интерфейс

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы, интерфейс, while

Хочу сделать в своей программе функцию отслеживания процессов и закрытия программы при их обнаружении, а именно снифферов-пакетов, которые отслеживают отправленные запросы. Знаю что делать это бесполезно, но от ламеров такая простая защита меня вполне устроит.

Набросал такой простой код:

```
static void KillThemAll()
{
    while (true)
    {
       if ((Process.GetProcessesByName("FirstProgram").Length > 0 || Process.GetProcessesByName("SecondProgram").Length > 0 || Process.GetProcessesByName("ThirdProgram").Length > 0) || Environment.HasShutdownStarted || FindWindow("", "FourProgram") != IntPtr.Zero || FindWindow("", "FiveProgram") != IntPtr.Zero)
       {
          Environment.Exit(0);
       }
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Далее после `InitializeComponent();` использую свою функцию `KillThemAll();` и пытаюсь запустить программу. Закрытие процессов происходит отлично, но интерфейс не появляется. Видимо из-за `while(true)` мой код становится недостижимым. Но как это исправить и заставить мои идеи работать? Надеюсь на Ваши предложения.

Comment: Ваш код без оформления, его читать невозможно.

Comment: @tym32167 Извиняюсь, не сразу разобрался как оформлять. Теперь всё нормально?

Comment: Да, теперь все понятно. Либо запускайте этот код в отдельном потоке, либо переписывайте его на асинхронное выполнение, либо оба варианта сразу. Сейчас этот код, запущенный в потоке пользовательского интерфейса не дает вашему интерфейсу ничего сделать.

Comment: Еще обратите внимание, что вы никак не используете процесс `Process p` внутри цикла. Так нужен ли вам этот цикл вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за помощь, переписал код.

Comment: Ну вот это тоже вроде лишнее `Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод Environment.Exit() универсален,в том плане,что он может завершить работу приложения из любого потока.
Достаточно в program.cs до вызова Application.Run(...); или после InitializeComponent,создать поток или задачу и запустить в ней цикл наподобие этого Task.Run(()=>SnifferDefender());,тогда цикл будет работать в другом потоке,а основной поток программы продолжит выполнение

Comment: это точно ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Да,именно то,чего и хочет добиться автор вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Да, это именно то, что я и хотел.

Comment: @Lukacho Большое спасибо за помощь, всё получилось)